# Можно ли в js в результате выполнения функции вернуть новое имя переменной, а не строку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

У меня есть такая функция. Я хочу, чтобы при выполнении условия  `if (fingersNew.has(String(adisTagByCmd(fingerNum))))` возвращалось новое имя переменной, дополненное словом Done. Например: fingerDone. Как это можно реализовать?

```
const chengeIcon = (fingerNum: number) => {
    let icon
    if (fingerNum < 10 && fingerNum >= 0) {
      icon = finger
    } else if (fingerNum === 10 || fingerNum === 13) {
      icon = fingers
    } else if (fingerNum === 14 || fingerNum === 15) {
      icon = palm
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown type of ', fingerNum, ' number')
    }
    if (fingersNew.has(String(adisTagByCmd(fingerNum)))) {
      return icon += 'Done'
      }
    } else {
      return icon
    }
  }
```

Comment: Что значит "возвращалось новое имя переменной"? У вас судя по коду вообще возвращается произвольная строка, которая не зависит от входных параметров функции (finger, fingers, palm... видимо, вовсе какие-то переменные из внешнего окружения)

Comment: Новое имя переменной из функции не вернуть...

Comment: "Что значит "возвращалось новое имя переменной"?" — у меня есть компонент React в который я импортирую несколько svg-иконок и каждая из них хранится в свой переменной (finger, fingerDone, fingers, fingersDone, palm, palmDone). В зависимости от наличия или отсутствия данных выводится либо одна, либо другая. Имена переменных для этих иконок отличаются только словом Done на конце, поэтому я хотел сделать функцию, которая сможет возвращать имя переменной дописывая Done при необходимости, но не знаю как это сделать.